# Onedrive not working

Tags: apt, login

I installed onedrive through `sudo apt install onedrive` and then tried running it by command `onedrive` (also tried with `sudo onedrive` had same result),
it gave me a url to go and login, and after that i copied the response url (url of redirected page) and pasted in the terminal but it gives me following error:

```
onedrive.OneDriveException@src/onedrive.d(874): HTTP request returned status code 400 (Bad Request)
{
    "correlation_id": "07df5a71-02a4-4c47-8c9a-fe85c87936d2",
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_codes": [
        9002313
    ],
    "error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: 4340c82b-6c44-4010-a831-46e8cbe57400\r\nCorrelation ID: 07df5a71-02a4-4c47-8c9a-fe85c87936d2\r\nTimestamp: 2020-10-14 17:56:02Z",
    "error_uri": "https:\/\/login.microsoftonline.com\/error?code=9002313",
    "timestamp": "2020-10-14 17:56:02Z",
    "trace_id": "4340c82b-6c44-4010-a831-46e8cbe57400"
}
----------------
??:? [0x5645dce759d9]
??:? [0x5645dce74cb5]
??:? [0x5645dce75b65]
??:? [0x5645dce73f58]
??:? [0x5645dce738c5]
??:? [0x5645dce817a8]
??:? void rt.dmain2._d_run_main2(char[][], ulong, extern (C) int function(char[][])*).runAll() [0x7f96d48879db]
??:? _d_run_main2 [0x7f96d48877ee]
??:? _d_run_main [0x7f96d488765d]
??:? __libc_start_main [0x7f96d44730b2]
??:? [0x5645dce4c5ed]
```

Any suggestions about what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The version of Onedrive available in the default Ubuntu repositories is old and buggy. To get the latest version, you need to install from the OpenSuSE Build Service. Refer to: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md for details.

If you don't want to use the OpenSuSE Build Service, you can compile it from source. For more information see

https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md

If you want to see a working version of Onedrive in default Ubuntu repositories, consider becoming the Onedrive package maintainer for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the buggy version, but the package you mentioned, clearly states `unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA`, so I was wondering if it's a trustworthy client since I haven't yet used too much third party clients and I don't know how to decide the legitimacy of a package(I'm new to ubuntu).

Comment: The PPA package can be 100% trusted.

If you want to change this, so that you dont have to use a PPA, or compile from source, please become the package maintainer for Ubuntu.